# Spivak Calculus, Chapter 9, Exercise 22(b)

Tags: limits, derivatives

Assuming $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is differentiable, how can one prove that
$$
f'(x) = \lim_{h,k \to 0^+} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x-k)}{h+k},
$$
an alternate expression to the usual limit definition of the derivative $f'(x)=\lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h$?

I figured the problem out for the special case of $k=h$: add and subtract $f(x)$ in the numerator of the expression. An $\epsilon$-$\delta$ requirement was not required to prove that $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h} = \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h$. This was part (a) of Exercise 9.22.

I also thought about sending $k \to 0^+$ first to simplify the function, and since $f$ is differentiable (therefore continuous), sending $k \to 0^+$ would reduce the original expression down to the familiar $\lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$. But then again we can't send $h \to 0^+$ and $k \to 0^+$ separately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**HINT**: You were on the right track to subtract and add $f(x)$ in the numerator. So then you'll have the sum of two fractions. You now need to do a similar trick with *multiplication* with each of those factors in order to make the usual difference quotients
$$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h \qquad\text{and}\qquad \frac{f(x+k)-f(x)}k$$
appear.

Comment: Am I on the right track so far: $$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x-k)}{h+k} = \frac h{h+k} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h + \frac k{h+k} \frac{f(x)-f(x-k)}k$$

Comment: Absolutely! You should get it now. (Perhaps you'll want to subtract $f'(x)$ in an appropriate way to give the rigorous proof.)

Comment: I knew an $\epsilon$-$\delta$ argument would work, but I was actually trying to send $h,k \to 0^+$ both sides of the equality. I'm not sure why that doesn't work so well, however. I would get on the RHS $0 f'(x) + 0 f'(x)$ ...

Comment: No, you can't send them separately to $0$. :) $\dfrac h{h+k}$ is bounded but has no limit. Etc.

Comment: Ah! I did not regard this as a multivariable function (e.g. $f(h,k) = \frac h{h+k}$)! When the problem wrote the notation "$\lim_{h,k \to 0^+}$" I think it is really trying to say "$\lim_{(h,k) \to (0,0)}$"

Comment: @Newdayrising: You don't need anything from multivariable calculus. It's only algebra that's going on here. Don't be misled. The way the other answer was written up has made you think there are 2-dimensional limit ideas; that is not true.

Comment: I can accept your criticism about posting complete answer early, but seriously, I am not misleading the op. If the question writes $h, k \to 0$, would there be the other rigorous interpretation instead of the multivariate one?

Comment: It's definitely the multivariable one

Comment: Look, guys. Spivak is a careful writer, and I'm fully aware that $h$ and $k$ make two variables. His intention is that a serious student working from his single-variable calculus book be capable of solving this problem. That student will need to understand that he needs $0<h<\delta_1$ to make $\left|\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h -f'(x)\right|<\epsilon$ and a similar $\delta_2$ for the $k$ limit. One needn't think about multivariable functions or about vectors in $\Bbb R^2$ to arrive at this.

Answer (score 3):

It's better to use an $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ argument to present a rigorous proof: that is, evaluating the difference between the operand and the objective $f'(x)$.

---

Details:
Given $\varepsilon > 0$, by the definition of $f'(x)$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $0 < h < \delta$ and $0 < k < \delta$ imply that

$$\left|\frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h}  - f'(x)\right| < \varepsilon,\qquad\left|\frac{f(x - k) - f(x)}{-k} - f'(x)\right| < \varepsilon.$$

Now if $\|(h, k) - (0, 0)\| < \delta$, we then have:
\begin{align*}
 & \left|\frac{f(x + h) - f(x - k)}{h + k}  - f'(x)\right|\\
= & \left|\frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h} \cdot \frac{h}{h + k} - f'(x)\frac{h}{h + k} + \frac{f(x - k) - f(x)}{-k} \cdot \frac{k}{h + k} - f'(x)\frac{k}{h + k}\right| \\ 
\leq & \left|\frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h}  - f'(x)\right| \frac{h}{h + k} + \left|\frac{f(x - k) - f(x)}{-k} - f'(x)\right|\frac{k}{h + k} \\
< & \varepsilon \frac{h}{h + k} + \varepsilon \frac{k}{h + k} \\
= & \varepsilon.
\end{align*}
This is precisely what we want to prove.

Note the condition $h > 0$ and $k > 0$ is crucial whence we can remove the absolute value.

Comment: Thanks for posting a complete answer when the OP was well on his way to working it all out himself. (end sarcasm)  Sometimes people just cannot resist ...

Comment: I think a rigorous $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ argument is the meat of this problem: most of students should be able to think about the add-subtract trick, yet finish it is not that obvious without invoking $\varepsilon$-$\delta$.

Comment: Notice that I added the "subtract the $f'(x)$". Why don't you let the person try before giving it all away? I realize you're an undergraduate as well, but sometimes it's OK not to show off and to let other people learn themselves.

Comment: You can keep working on your own without looking at it.

Comment: Or you could just have waited and if the OP asked after another hour for a complete proof, then you could have given yours if my hints were not helpful. This is a general problem with this site, although some people are on your side and not on mine.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment, so I'm posting here my understanding of answering this problem:

Since by hypothesis $f'(x)=\lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h = \lim_{k \to 0^+} \frac{f(x)-f(x-k)}k$...

For all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta_1 > 0$ such that $0 < h-0<\delta_1$ implies $\left|\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h-f'(x)\right|<\epsilon$.

For all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta_2 > 0$ such that $0 < k-0 <\delta_2$ implies $\left|\frac{f(x)-f(x-k)}k-f'(x)\right|<\epsilon$.

<s>Choose</s>  $\require{enclose}
     \enclose{horizontalstrike}{\delta := \min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}}$<s>.</s> Choose $\delta_1=\delta_2=\epsilon$. Then
\begin{align}
&\left|\frac{f(x+h)-f(x-k)}{h+k}-f'(x) \right| \\ 
&\le \frac{h}{h + k} \left|\frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h}  - f'(x)\right| + \frac{k}{h + k} \left|\frac{f(x) - f(x-k)}{k} - f'(x)\right| \\ 
&= \frac{h}{h + k} \left|\frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h}  - f'(x)\right| + \frac{k}{h + k} \left|\frac{f(x+k) - f(x)}{k} - f'(x)\right| \\ 
&< \frac{h}{h+k} \delta_1 + \frac{k}{h+k} \delta_2 \\ 
&= \frac{h}{h+k} \epsilon + \frac{k}{h+k} \epsilon \\ 
&= \epsilon
\end{align}

Comment: I do not know if this is correct, but I am trying to avoid my brief misunderstanding of being "required" to use multivariable calculus notation, as Ted Shifrin mentioned to me about.

Comment: You need multivariate calculus notation to even *formulate* the problem, when you write $\lim_{h,k\to 0}$, so it is pretty much impossible to answer the question without using it.

Comment: I've posted my pedagogical rebuttal above. But you do not need the minimum. Spivak intends you merely to say that if you make $0<h<\delta_1$ and $0<k<\delta_2$ (using the single-variable limit definition), then you will succeed.